# What is the difference in running GWT in differnt Web Application mode in eclipse?

Tags: gwt, google-eclipse-plugin, gwt-super-dev-mode

In eclipse what is the difference running GWT Web Application in different Mode.

- Web Application
- Web Application (GWT Classic Dev Mode)
- Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode)
- Web Application (running on an external server)

[image: Eclipse Run AS]

Comment: Google.Google.Google.Probably stackoverflow will come up in the top results.Then,refer that particular question.Otherwise continue googling.

Comment: "Probably" but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just started to use GWT, you can focus exclusively on Super Dev Mode for developing and debugging your applications.

This document explains [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) and the differences with Classic Dev Mode.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei , Yes I am new and got confused with multiple modes. I am currently using Super and will continue using that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Web Application - Launches GWT Classic Dev Mode by default
- Web Application (GWT Classic Dev Mode) - Launches Classic Dev Mode
- Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode) - Launches Super Dev Mode
- Web Application (running on an external server) - Launches Classic Dev Mode with a remote server wizard. This can be used if a custom server is used.

All of the launcher shortcuts are nearly the same with the exception that they add or remove program arguments in the launch editor depending on shortcut used.